# Uploading a model with a file to the ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a simple application that works like a cookbook with ASP.NET Core Web API and Blazor WASM. When creating the functionality to add a new recipe, I have encountered a certain problem whose solution is not obvious to me.

The API controller's post method should receive the RecipeDto model.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadRecipe(RecipeDto uploadedRecipe)
{
    var maxAllowedFiles = 1;
    long maxFileSize = 1024 * 500;
    var imageStoragePath = _config.GetValue<string>("Paths:RecipeImgPath");

    try
    {
        if (uploadedRecipe.RecipeImg.Length == 0 || uploadedRecipe.RecipeImg.Length > maxFileSize)
        {
            return BadRequest(); //TODO - implement proper request description
        }
        else
        {
            var trustedFileNameForFileStorage = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            var path = Path.Combine(_config.GetValue<string>("Paths:RecipeImgPath"), trustedFileNameForFileStorage);
            await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
            await uploadedRecipe.RecipeImg.CopyToAsync(fs);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The `RecipeDto` model has a `List<IngredientDto>` property that stores information about the recipe ingredients.

```
public class RecipeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string? PrepDescription { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool LunchBox { get; set; }
    public string Diet_Category { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string RecipeImgBase64 { get; set; }
    public IFormFile RecipeImg { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientDto> Ingredients { get; set;}
}

public class IngredientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Countable { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I write the frontend of the application in Blazor wasm. According to the Microsoft documentation, I can upload the file as a `MultipartFormDataContent` and add the file content and the content of the other properties to it as a string.

```
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    foreach(var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
    {
        try
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());

            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            content.Add(
            content: fileContent,
            name: "\"file\"",
            fileName: "Test");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }  
}
```

However, manually bind all properties to the `MultipartFormDataContent` format by string and then read and check them, with the `RecipeDto` model complicated enough, it seems very difficult to implement correctly and without errors.

The second idea I have is to send the image in Base64 form directly in a Body Json file.

How should such an upload look in a production setting?